# Stop Distribution Upgrade Message Globally

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, update-manager, awn

So I am an IT consultant and a business i do work for wanted to make the switch to Linux on about 25 machines since their software is web based and Linux is more secure. I set them up with a custom Ubuntu Remix Replacing Unity with an AWN panel on the bottom and A Menu to mimic the layout of windows and installed Likewise Open FOR AD/DC connection and logins.

Problem is, after making the iso and installing it on a test machine it immediately pops up the update center at every new user login asking to upgrade to 14.04. This completely breaks both AWN and Likewise if done (not that they could since they arent sudoers but its annoying), so id like to force the "Never tell me about a new version" setting globally. It already does updates automatically unattended, but this message pops up at every login for every user.

Any remedy? Is this setting stored in the user profile? and if so can this config be added somewhere ins/etc/skel/ to automatically inherit that setting?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: No one has any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `prompt` to `never`.  As this is just a text file, it should be trivial if you have other configuration management going on.

EDIT:
That worked on one of my boxes, but not the other.  `sudo apt-get remove update-manager-core` simply removed the update check functionality.  Again, this should be something you can do if you are making release images for your environment.

Comment: This seems to have worked. i only had to change the config to make it work. rebuilt the image and it all seems to be ok now. Thanks!